# Why am I in danger of being blocked?

Tags: discussion

I was just about to ask a question when I saw this warning:

```
Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
```

I have only asked one question and it has 4 up-votes.

This [information](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) doesn't seem to explain the reason. So why am I in danger of being blocked?

Edit: I've gone ahead and asked my question now.

Comment: You sure you got this notice on Travel.SE?

Comment: @MeNoTalk Yes. It no longer appears though.

Comment: Note that while the question had upvotes, it was closed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have some deleted posts that you have forgotten about that were bad. Do you see a link to "Show recently deleted posts" on your profile?

One cure for being "about to be blocked" is to ask a good question that is well received. This may be why the notice no longer appears for you.

Comment: I don't see that link. I'm pretty sure I had only ever asked that one question before yesterday. It being closed probably caused the problem but as I say in another comment - one "bad" post shouldn't have triggered the block message.

Comment: Historically, people did not get warnings. They just got blocked and by then it was generally too late. A warning after a single post is certainly not in danger of being too late :-). The intent is to get new users to be more careful asking, and the evidence shows that it works (I'm not commenting on your case, just on stats gathered as part of the quality project.)

Comment: It's all good. Thanks for explaining the possible cause.

Answer (score 2):

My only theory is that your [Paris one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/what-are-the-hidden-parts-of-paris-worth-visiting-experiencing) had both a downvote and was closed.  Albeit two years ago.

[There's a theory on meta.SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259979/bad-question-warning) that bad history might generate comments like this for quite a while until you've worked into more of a 'positive' balance.  Go figure.

But we've seen users with far more closed questions with actual poor content, so I suspect it's just an over-reacting warning - I wouldn't worry any time just yet ;)

Comment: I thought it was an "over-reacting warning" and didn't take it too seriously. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here I would say that this might be due to you having only a negative record, with that question closed as off-topic (or something similar) back in 2013, without any positive ones to counter the effect.

Comment: The information says "One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site." so even if that one question was "bad" I shouldn't really get the blocked warning.